# GET nonexistent Neo4J node with REST API - improvements?

Tags: rest, neo4j

GET nonexistent node with REST API throws Exception (costly in Java afaik) - it's just a 404 as expected, but I can do without the exception. Handling HTTP GET myself and unwrapping the response manually would give the control I need to avoid the exception but that's tedious

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET 
   http://<host>:7474/db/data/**123123** returned a response status of 404 Not Found
        at xxx.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:686)
        at xxx.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
        at xxx.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
```

`(xxx = com.sun.jersey.api.client)`

the 123123 is just a nodeID I know does not exist - using that for testing.

Surely a more efficient way to check node's existence? In this case I need to do the GET using nodeID - I'm aware of how to dot his with an indexed property (or label if using 2.0xxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you maybe do it with Cypher and check for no rows as return?

```
start n=node(123) return n;
```

?

Comment: I could yes, and that's what I'll have to do - should be more efficient than a throw/catch.